# OpenCV: odd projection with large values

Tags: python, opencv, 3d

Whenever I try to project 3D points into the image plane with cv2.projectPoints I get really large values. Even with [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html) my projected axis looks like this: [image: weird looking projected axis]

I've tried checking my calibration matrices, but they look quite normal:

```
intrinsic camera parameters:
[[444., 0., 316.],
 [0., 414., 263.],
 [0.,  0.,    1.]]

distortion coeffs:
[[0.09, -0.13, -0.03, 0.0, 0.39]]

rotation vector:
[[1.27, -1.16, -1.12]]

translation vector:
[[0.02, 0.5, -0.5]]
```

Finally, the projected axis values are

```
[[173.64,     798.27],
 [311.09,     807.81],
 [20258.80, -7491.46]]  # really large value
```

The detected corners are those of the sheet of paper. Since there are only four corners that serve as a "guide" (instead of the 42 corners used in the tutorial), I don't know if that is what's making the projection really fuzzy. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Edit. the original axis is just the identity matrix.

Edit 2. Code:

```py
while True:
  _, frame = vcap.read()
  key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
  if key == ord("q"):
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      break
  
  # preprocess image
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
 
  # fetch points
  corners = find_sheet_of_paper(thresh)
  corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)

  # rotation and translation vectors for projection                                                                                  
  _, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(object_points, corners, mtx, dist)

  # project 3d points on 2d image
  image_points, _ = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
  image_points = np.squeeze(image_points)
  frame = draw_axis(frame, corners, image_points)
  
  cv2.imshow("", frame)
```

The `find_sheet_of_paper` function returns an array of the paper's coordinates. The `draw_axis` function is the same as the one in the link. And `object_points` is just a meshgrid:

```
object_points = [
  [0., 0., 0.],
  [1., 0., 0.],
  [0., 1., 0.],
  [1., 1., 0.]
]
```

Comment: Where is the code you created / used to perform the calibration and draw the axes?

Comment: I used [this same tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) for camera calibration; clearly, I used my own images to calibrate the camera, but the program I used is that one.

Comment: In the object_points variable, try reducing the value of 1. to 0.5 or less. It worked for me in project related to aruco marker pose estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured this out. Since there are only four points that are being detected, the data is kind of noisy. In these cases where we can't rely too much on the detections, it is better to use the RANSAC algorithm. So, instead of using the default iterative method, we should do:

```py
_, rvecs, tvecs, _ = cv2.solvePnPRansac(
    object_points, corners, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_P3P
)
```

Lucky me, the function requires exactly four detections. This is the output:
[image: projected axis]